# Discord.js arguments

Tags: discord.js

I am still fairly new to discord.js and javascript, and I am having a bit of trouble when it comes to arguments

[This is to show how I'd want the command to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwC7N.jpg)

```
case 'poll':
                args.shift();
                const title = args.join(" ");
                const options = 
                    pollEmbed(message, title, options);
                break;
        };
```

this is my code for it
the title is the question while the options I want to be the answer choices

[The second image shows how it is handling the arguments right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBPGE.jpg)

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to achieve in the options variable, but since are commands usually (probably in your case as well) stored in arrays, you can refer to them by indexing. It may be the pollEmbed function that is causing the problem, with this little code it is hard to tell, feel free to show more.

Comment: The pollEmbed connects to the package discord.js-poll-embed found here
https://github.com/saanuregh/discord.js-poll-embed/blob/master/index.js

Comment: So what exactly do you want the options constant to do?

Comment: It is a poll command so the options would be the answer choices within the poll

Comment: I am not very familiar with that poll package but I guess the options should be array as well?

Comment: The poll package is just a way to process the poll results and send out an embed I just need to provide the title (question of the poll) and the options (answer choices for the poll) for it to display properly, However I am unfamiliar with arguments so I do not know how to isolate certain parts of the input message

Comment: Yes I understand that. I am gonna assume that the options are in array. To get only arguments from command, try args.shift(). This will extract the first item (y!poll) from the array. Now you can pass in the title as args[0] and options as args[1], args[2] or just use a simple for loop and pass them from that. Did this help?

Comment: It helped for the title but not as much for the options

Comment: I am looking at the documentation on GitHub and as it says the options are array of strings. Please, provide your current code.

Comment: I edited the message with my current code

Comment: I posted an answer please tell me if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have command like this:

```
y!poll title answer1 answer2
```

First, remove the command itself

```
args.shift();
```

Then pass it into function like this:

```
var title = args[0];
var options = ["Your options here"];
var message = [];
args.shift()

for (var i = 0; i <= args.length - 1; i++) {
   message.push(args[i]);
}

pollEmbed(message, title, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `args` with `message.content.split(' ')` which splits each word from the sentence and then you can use `args[1]` or anything inside `[]` to get different words from the sentence

example: `!poll me you none --title Who is the best`
where me = `args[1]`, you = `args[2]`, none = `args[3]`

and title can be defined using `const title = message.content.split('--')[1]`